# "Sentences" and "Formulas" in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy

Tags: logic

I have quite a bit of issues with an [article about classical logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Dedu) in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (SEP) and I am not sure if it is me or the article:

> We now introduce a deductive system, D, for our languages. As above, we define an argument to be a non-empty collection of sentences in the formal language, one of which is designated to be the conclusion. If there are any other sentences in the argument, they are its premises.[1] By convention, we use “Γ”, “Γ′”, “Γ1”, etc, to range over sets of sentences, and we use the letters “ϕ”, “ψ”, “θ”, uppercase or lowercase, with or without subscripts, to range over single sentences. We write “Γ,Γ′” for the union of Γ and Γ′, and “Γ,ϕ” for the union of Γ with {ϕ}.
>
> We write an argument in the form ⟨Γ,ϕ⟩
> , where Γ is a set of sentences, the premises, and ϕ is a single sentence, the conclusion. Remember that Γ may be empty. We write Γ⊢ϕ to indicate that ϕ is deducible from Γ, or, in other words, that the argument ⟨Γ,ϕ⟩ is deducible in D. We may write Γ⊢Dϕ to emphasize the deductive system D. We write ⊢ϕ or ⊢Dϕ to indicate that ϕ can be deduced (in D) from the empty set of premises.

"we define an argument to be a non-empty collection of sentences in the formal language, one of which is designated to be the conclusion. If there are any other sentences in the argument, they are its premises."

As far as I know, we are not allowed to write any sentence not using the formal language, so what are those premises? Do they mean "other open formulas" instead of "sentences"? Be [1] leads to

> "It is possible to develop a system which allows open formulas to appear in arguments. This would have a direct impact on our treatment of the quantifiers, as we would have to be much more careful about which variables we were using. Allowing formulas to appear in arguments simplifies some things and complicates others."

Note, that now they say "open formulas" at one point and "formulas" later. Other documents I read say a "term" is a thing that is not truth-apt, while a formula is truth-apt (so basically a closed formula).

In the second paragraph, they write "argument in the form ⟨Γ,ϕ⟩ , where Γ is a set of sentences, the premises, and ϕ is a single sentence, the conclusion", but I thought from above that one those "other sentences" are its premises... What is going on here?

The issue I have here, is that the SEP does not seem to get "sentence", "formula", "open formula" straight in their own text - or is it me who is not getting it?

After all the SEP is [peer-reviewed and everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_Encyclopedia_of_Philosophy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion might be a result of interpreting this passage incorrectly (it's arguably a bit ambiguous):

"we define an argument to be a non-empty collection of sentences in the formal language, one of which is designated to be the conclusion. If there are any other sentences in the argument, they are its premises."

The "other sentences" are not other sentences *not in the formal language*, they're other sentences *besides the one designated as the conclusion*. They are still sentences in the formal language.

Here's an attempt at rewriting it to be a little more clear:

"we define an argument to be a non-empty collection of sentences in the formal language, together with a designated sentence within that collection. We call this designated sentence the conclusion of the argument, and we call the other sentences in the collection the premisses of the argument."

Answer (score 5):

> The issue I have here, is that the SEP does not seem to get "sentence", "formula", "open formula" straight in their own text - or is it me who is not getting it?

I'm not seeing any issues from the paragraphs you've quoted, but maybe I'm not quite understanding your confusion. It might be that you're unaware that there are two kinds of formulas: open formulas and closed formulas (also called 'sentences').  Open formulas have free variables and closed formulas (sentences) do not.

> As far as I know, we are not allowed to write any sentence not using the formal language, so what are those premises? Do they mean "other open formulas" instead of "sentences"?

They are sentences which means that they are not open formulas.

> In the second paragraph, they write "argument in the form ⟨Γ,ϕ⟩ , where Γ is a set of sentences, the premises, and ϕ is a single sentence, the conclusion", but I thought from above that one those "other sentences" are its premises... What is going on here?

The "other sentences" refers exactly to $\Gamma$, the premises. I'm not seeing conflicting statements.

> Note, that now they say "open formulas" at one point and "formulas" later.

Open formulas are formulas. The 'open' adjective means that it contains free variables. If they just use the word 'formulas', then they probably want to include both sentences and open formulas.

Hopefully this clears up some confusion

Comment: Yes, it did, thanks! The misunderstanding actually came from the point that Andrew made, but you helped flesh it out too!